# BigInteger in Java and Randomness

Tags: randomness, pseudo-random-generator

I'm looking for some PRNGs and – as I have been using Java for a long period of time – I thought that the `BitInteger` class, together with the `Random` class, could both generate some large pseudo random numbers.

Are the algorithms behind those generations cryptographically secure, or is it just some sort of `a + (b - c) mod d` or similar operation?

Comment: Exactly what _algorithms_ are you considering in the phrase of the question ending in a question mark?

Comment: Just use the `SecureRandom` class.

Comment: I was considering the algorithms behind the Random and BigInteger class.

Comment: @vlad you were considering wrong :)

Comment: BigInteger does not contain PRNG code at all. It *uses* RNGs only. Btw, the statement to use SecureRandom is even in the [JavaDoc of the Random class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html). Last sentence of the first paragraph

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presuming this [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#next%28int%29) is correct, the answer is no, these numbers are not cryptographically secure. The Random class uses a [linear congruential formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) with a 48 bit seed. For most purposes it is not enough even if you only require 48 bit security. Given a fairly low number of outputs from a LCG, it is possible to derive the seed, even if only a few bits of each seed iteration are used. That question has been answered [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2086/predicting-values-from-a-linear-congruential-generator).