# Generate random number which should depend on key

Tags: random-number-generator, pseudo-random-function, linear-cryptanalysis

i want to generate random number for example from [1..100]. The algorithm which would generates random number should work similarly like a *"Linear congruential generator"*, like this:

$X_{n+1}≡(aX_n + c)\ (mod\ m)$

Where:
$c$ - increment should be something like 98979817
$a$ - should be used for security and should be great number
$X_n$ - initial number

However, I can't use this formula because my $m\ (mod m)$ is 100 so it's $m < c$ and $m < a$. While it should be $m > c$ and $m > a$.

Maybe there is something similar which is more secure than this?

Comment: If something can't be simply twisted to work, one has to look for alternatives. I suppose that a sufficiently good scheme that can be adapted for use in your applications could be RC4, see Wiki.

Comment: Beware that RC4 has some significant flaws. Careless operation might be vulnerable. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4#Security

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any [Pseudo Random Number Generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_Random_Number_Generator) using a [Linear Congruential Generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator), and no cryptography, is going to be unsafe, or at the very least unsatisfactory, per the criteria in our [FAQ](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/faq). Likely, a skilled adversary would be able to predict future output from some amount of past output with moderate work; at best, that won't happen, but there will be no sound argument that it is not possible. There are [many](http://www.enseignement.polytechnique.fr/profs/informatique/Francois.Morain/Master1/Crypto/projects/Stern87.pdf) [more](http://asterix.cs.gsu.edu/crypto/p129-boyar.pdf) or [less](http://www.nccgroup.com/media/18592/weak_randomness.pdf) difficult to read papers making that point. A recent [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2086/predicting-values-from-a-linear-congruential-generator), another [there](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/4306/6211), further illustrate this. If the *more secure* requirement is to be taken any seriously, it is best to forget the LCG entirely, and use cryptography.

There should be three steps in a secure "Random Number Generator depending on a key" producing an output sequence uniformly distributed on the integers in $[1…100]$:

1. [Stretching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching) of the initial key. The purpose is to make [brute force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack) search of the key infeasible, or at least costly. That is superfluous if the key is already *both* wide enough (say 120 bit or more; 256 is aplenty) *and* chosen uniformly at random; in almost any other case, including when a human is expected to remember (or worse choose) the key, a deliberately slow transformation of that input is highly recommended. In many cases (notably: the combination of multiple users and use of password), the initial key should be [salted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) while stretched. The standard building block for these functions is a Password-Based Key Derivation Function. A common one is [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2); [Bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) is much safer; the current state of the art is [Scrypt](http://www.tarsnap.com/scrypt.html).
2. A [Cryptographically Secure Pseudo Random Number Generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator), or equivalently the Keystream Generator of a secure [Stream Cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher). We'll feed it the (possibly stretched) key (in the input named *seed* or key), and then it will output on demand practically any number of random-looking bits that we may want. The design of that cryptographic primitive strives to make that output computationally indistinguishable from random by an adversary not knowing the seed. There are a plethora of CSPRNG and Stream Ciphers to choose among, and the best choice depends on context. If it must be fast on any modern CPU, [Salsa20](http://cr.yp.to/snuffle.html#specification) comes to mind.
3. Post-conditioning to obtain outputs uniformly distributed on the desired output interval $[u…v]$, here $[1…100]$. One simple suitable technique (slightly wasteful, but that does not matter since the CSPRNG is likely fast) is to:

   - Find the lowest integer $w$ such that $2^w\ge v-u+1$; here that is $w=7$, since $128\ge100$.
   - Obtain $w$ bits using the CSPRNG, forming an integer $r$ in range $[0…2^w-1]$, until $r<v-u+1$ (otherwise, discard $r$ and repeat this step).
   - Output $u+r$, and proceed to the previous step as needed to obtain more output.

---

If being simple and based on a LCG is important, and being secure is pointless as long as the output is good enough to pass some simple statistical test, the following procedure builds a LCG and post-condition its output (I assume the range $[u…v]$ has width no more than about $2^{16}$).

1. Choose $m=2^{64}$ (or a convenient higher power of $2$), $a=3141592621$, $c=1$ (this conforms to more detailed advice in [TAOCP](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/taocp.html) Volume 2, section 3.6; except that I kept $a$ unchanged, rather than taking the risk to scale it with $m$); the C or C++ type `unsigned long long`, if available, is suitable for implicit reduction modulo some appropriate implementation-dependent $m$.
2. Find $w$ from the interval $[u…v]$ as above (here $w=7$ for $[1…100]$).
3. Set $X$ to the key truncated to the bit width of $m$ (Repeat: security is out of scope! But still, it does not harm to feed other key bits in $c$, as long as it is forced to be odd).
4. Set $X$ to $a⋅X+c\bmod m$; in C that's `X = a*X+c;`.
5. Form $r$ in range $[0…2^w-1]$ from the $w$ *high* bits of $X$; in C that's `r = X>>(W-w);` where `W` is the bit width of the unsigned integer type chosen for `X`, and $m=2^{\mathtt W}$.
6. If $r\ge v-u+1$, proceed to step 4.
7. Output $u+r$, and proceed to step 4 as needed to obtain more output.

Answer (score -4):

For your purposes the following should be adequately secure:
Choose $m$ as large as is convenient for the data type you're using.
Choose a random odd $a$ and whatever $c$ you like. 
The sequence of successive X values will look random. To get your random number in the range 1 to 100 inclusive, calculate $1+(X_n \mod 100)$

Comment: This technique generates numbers that are appreciably biased. Independently of that, it is not secure in a cryptographic sense: the state (and thus all forthcoming and previous output) can be recovered with little effort from a small list of consecutive outputs.

Comment: There's worse: if $m$ is even (as implied by _$m$ as large as is convenient_, which points to a power of 2), then the low bit of what's generated is constant (for even $c$) or toggling between 0 and 1 (for odd $c$). Fact is: both choice of parameters of the LCG, and how its output is reduced to range [1..100], are deeply flawed.

Comment: @fgrieu What you say is true. I forgot the lower bit would toggle and should have insisted on an odd $m$. However the level of my answer was appropriate for the question. We both know that any simple scheme based on a linear congruential generator is flawed and therefore "Streetboy" is not looking for something secure but needs instead to be told that he doesn't need to set m to 100 just because he needs numbers in that range. Now give me some upvotes!

Comment: Odd $m$ is not enough: for a post-conditioning of such a LCG using $\bmod 100$, it is necessary (not necessarily sufficient) that $\gcd(m,100)=1$; with $m=2^{2^k}-1$ and $k>1$ (a nice fit for odd and _as large as is convenient for the data type_), that's not the case, and the rightmost digit of the output in base 5 will follow a cyclic pattern of length 5 (or be constant); that will be discernible to the naked eye in base 10. Also the question asks _something more secure_; to me that's antagonist with _not looking for something secure_.

Comment: @fgrieu You're quite right. Although I'm sure it's more fun to pick holes in other people's answers than it is to craft your own, now you've already expended all this effort, why don't you craft a "proper" answer and see whether it gets accepted eh?