# How to attack a fixed LCG with partial output?

Tags: cryptanalysis, pseudo-random-generator

To show some colleague programmers exactly how broken C's `rand()` is (at least on Windows) I decided to break it. So everyone knows the exact parameters, MSVC's implementation is as follows:

```
uint32_t state;

int rand() {
    state = state * 214013 + 2531011;
    return (state >> 16) & 0x7fff;
}
```

Because the top bit never affects anything but the next top bit in the next state and is never returned you could see this as the LCG $X_{n+1} \equiv (214013X_n + 2531011) \mod 2^{31}$ where at each iteration we only get to see the top 15 bits.

The problem is, **I have not found any references that attack fixed LCG's with partial output.**

Of course it requires only 2-3 calls of the `rand()` function to enable a bruteforce attack with at most $2^{16}$ operations on the secret part of the state, but that's hardly a break. Something similar would not be feasible with larger constants and a larger modulus.

So far I've been unable to find a break that shows this generator to be severely broken. I'm interested in results on similar LCG's that can be transformed to an attack on this one.

P.S.: If an attack exists that could be done on a graphical calculator without any programming, it increases how convincingly I can show the generator to be broken. But this is just bonus points.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Notations:

- $v=u\bmod m$ means $m$ divides $u-v$ and $0\le v<m$, including if $u<0$.
- All variables are non-negative integers (except for the above).
- $a=214013$, $b=2531011$ are the LCG parameters.
- $X_n$ is the 31-bit state with $X_{n+1}=(a\cdot X_n+b)\bmod 2^{31}$.
- $R_n=\lfloor X_n/2^{16}\rfloor$ is the 15-bit output.
- $S_n=X_n-2^{16}\cdot R_n$ is the hidden 16-bit portion of the state.

Assume we have the first few outputs $R_0$, $R_1$.. and want to find $X_0$.

We derive:
$$\big((2^{16}\cdot R_1+S_1)\bmod 2^{31}\big)=\big((a\cdot (2^{16}\cdot R_0+S_0)+b)\bmod 2^{31}\big)$$
$$2^{16}\cdot R_1-a\cdot2^{16}R_0-b+S_1\equiv a\cdot S_0\pmod{2^{31}}$$
Using that $S_1<2^{16}$ and defining $r=2^{16}-1-S_1<2^{16}$, that becomes:
$$2^{16}\cdot R_1-a\cdot2^{16}\cdot R_0-b+2^{16}-1\equiv a\cdot S_0+r\pmod{2^{31}}$$
Defining $K$ as the quotient of the Euclidean division of $a\cdot S_0+r$ by $2^{31}$, it comes:
$$\big((2^{16}\cdot R_1-a\cdot2^{16}\cdot R_0-b+2^{16}-1)\bmod2^{31}\big)+2^{31}\cdot K=a\cdot S_0+r$$
Using that $r<2^{16}\le a$, we find that $S_0$ must be the quotient of the Euclidean division of the new left side of the equation by $a$, and $r$ the reminder; we derive:
$$S_0=\Big\lfloor{{\big((2^{16}\cdot R_1-a\cdot2^{16}\cdot R_0-b+2^{16}-1)\bmod 2^{31}\big)+2^{31}\cdot K}\over a}\Big\rfloor$$

---

Therefore the following outputs the possible values for $X_0$ given the first two outputs $R_0$ and $R_1$, by trying all possible values of $K$:

- Compute $T=(2^{16}\cdot R_1-a\cdot2^{16}\cdot R_0-b+2^{16}-1)\bmod 2^{31}$
  Notice that $T+2^{31}\cdot K=a\cdot S_0+r$ with $S_0<2^{16}$ and $r<2^{16}$
- For $K$ from $0$ to $\big\lfloor\big((2^{16}-1)\cdot(a+1)-T\big)/2^{31}\big\rfloor$

  - If $\big((T+2^{31}\cdot K)\bmod a\big)<2^{16}$

    - Output $\big\lfloor(T+2^{31}\cdot K)/a\big\rfloor+2^{16}\cdot R_0$

The quantity $(T+2^{31}\cdot K)\bmod a$ tested in the loop is $r$, hence the test's bound. $\big\lfloor(T+2^{31}\cdot K)/a\big\rfloor$ is $S_0$. What's output is a candidate $X_0$, since $S_n=X_n-2^{16}\cdot R_n$. It is easy to filter these candidates using $R_2$.

This works for any $a\ge2^{16}$. With the parameters at hand, the loop is performed at most $7$ times, with typically $2\pm1$ outputs. I can run the algorithm with pen and paper, and some would be able to perform it mentally.

The method works regardless of the bit size $x$ of $X$, an output $R$ with $x/2$ high bits (give or take a constant), and $a$ big enough that the attack works: the cost is $O(x^2\cdot a/2^{x/2})$ using standard arithmetic algorithms. I think we could avoid most values of $K$ that do not pass the test, bringing the cost to $O(x^2)$ even for huge $a$ (and [quoting Bruce Schneier](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4270#section-6) attributing that saying to the NSA: "Attacks always get better; they never get worse").

When $a$ is too small to carry that attack, a trivial attack applies, recovering the state $X_0$ from most to least significant bits, at a rate of about $\log_2a$ additional bits for each additional $R_n$.

Improvement: if $a$ is small or otherwise unfavorable, we can use $R_j$ rather than $R_1$, replacing $a$ with $a_j=a^j\bmod2^{31}$ for some $j>1$ giving a favorable $a_j$ (a small maximum $K$), and replacing $b$ with $b_j=b\cdot(1+a+\dots+a^{j-1})\bmod2^{31}$. That allows to efficiently tackle much larger modulus!

---

Generally speaking, Linear Congruential Generators are very poor from a cryptographic standpoint, even when some post-processing is applied; see [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2087/555) for an example.

More often than not, Linear Congruential Generators are not even suitable for simulation purposes. To demonstrate this to the incredulous, generate a million values using the LCG in the question; count how many times each of the 32768 values is reached; and either compute the standard deviation of that, or graph the counts sorted by increasing values; repeat with a sound RNG, and compare.

Comment: Could you explain the math behind your equations, I'm a little confused how the $S_1$ turned into $2^{16} - 1$

Comment: @fgrieu I think the part that is unclear (for me at least) is how you got to the formula after "Using that S1<a, we derive" . There, it looks like you just replaced `S1` with `S^16 - 1`?

Comment: @bennofs: : you (and Vishwa Iyer) are absolutely right. Further, I was using a potentially different $K$ before and after that second _"We derive"_. This is hopefully rigorous now. Thanks for pinpointing the issue!

Comment: @fgrieu I understand the math a little better, so from my understand, you defined $r$ just to simply the equation better? And could you explain how you got the ranges for $K$ with your loop? And when you were deriving $S_0$ where did the $r$ go? Did it disappear because floor($r$/$a$) = $0$?

Comment: @fgrieu sorry i wasn't clear on my question. I'm talking about the equation where you solved for $S_0$, where did $r$ go? Also, shouldn't $K = \text{floor}(a \cdot S_0 + r - T)/2^{31}$, or am I missing something? I don't know where the $2^{16} \cdot a - 1$ came from.

Comment: @Vishia: $r$ was introduced only to make things simpler. It could be derived as the remainder of the Euclidean division by $a$ of which $S_0$ is the quotient, but that is not needed (and was thus removed). I now detail how $K$ is constructed, and the derivation of its upper bound (which I slightly improved/reduced). $K$ is not directly computed; it's upper bound is computed, then $K$ is sequentially searched.

Answer (score 5):

You already answered your own question: given the output from 2 calls to the `rand()` function and $2^{16}$ steps of computation, you can recover the internal state completely, simply by brute-forcing the parts of the state that you are not aware of.  That *is* a break.

You say it's "hardly a break", but that is too-narrow thinking.  A break is a break; anything that suffices to predict future outputs of the generator *is* a break.  It *does* break Window's `rand()` implementation.

Maybe you are wondering whether *some other generator* that looks *sorta like* Window's `rand()`, but is not Window's `rand()`, would be breakable.  Well, that's a different question.  The answer to that will depend upon what specifically you have in mind -- but regardless, at that point we're not talking about Window's `rand()` any longer.  The break you've got is already good enough to show that Window's `rand()` should not be used for cryptographic purposes.  It's plenty adequate to show how broken Window's `rand()` is.

If this doesn't count as "good enough" of an attack, then probably your question isn't really a question about cryptography, but something else -- because for cryptographic purposes, this is a valid break.

---

That said, there is a slight improvement on the attack.  I believe you can build a meet-in-the-middle attack that needs about $2 \times 2^8$ steps of computation and 2 outputs from `rand()`, and that infers its internal state.

Here's the idea.  Suppose you observe the top 16 bits of $X_0$.  Now write $X_0 = c + 2^8 d + e$, where $0 \le d,e < 2^8$ and $c$ is a known constant.  Notice that this means

$$X_1 = (214013 c + 2531011) + 2^8 \cdot 214013 d + 214013 e.$$

The first part ($214013 c + 2531011$) is a known constant, so we have

$$X_1 = \text{known} + \text{known} \times d + \text{known} \times e.$$

or in other words,

$$X_1 - \text{known} - \text{known} \times d = \text{known} \times e.$$

Now we're set up to do a meet-in-the-middle attack.  We know the top 16 bits of $X_1$.  We can enumerate all $2^8$ possibilities for $e$, calculate the resulting top 16 bits of the right-hand side, and store them in a table.  We can then enumerate all $2^8$ possibilities for $d$, calculate the resulting top 16 bits of the left-hand side, and look it up in the table to check for a match.  When we guess them right, we should find a match.

Comment: I'm looking to show that `rand()` is unsuitable for nearly any purpose, rather than just cryptographic purposes. And I'm looking for 2 things here: either a better attack requiring less computation (preferably to be done with just a graphical calculator), or some reference recommendations for breaking LCG's with partial output. And my "break" doesn't work anymore if we'd change `state` to `uint64_t` (and change the shift to 48).

Comment: @nightcracker, in that case, it sounds like your question is not about cryptography per se, so I don't think it is on-topic here.  The cryptographic aspect of the question has been answered....

Comment: How so? The existence of a $2^{16}$ attack does not mean all further research on attacks should be stopped - especially considering that the internal state is only twice as large as that.

Comment: @nightcracker, I think it does mean that.  A $2^{16}$ attack means the generator is broken.  It means absolutely no one should use the generator.  At that point, who cares whether there is a $2^8$ attack?  How will that affect your decision-making?  If news of a $2^8$ attack will cause you to avoid the generator, when news of a $2^{16}$ attack wouldn't, then there is something wrong with your decision-making.  P.S. If your question is about other generators *like* the Windows rand(), but different (say with larger parameters), then that's a different question: post a new question.

Answer (score 3):

**Related to *"show some colleague programmers"*…**

You could code and use a smaller 8-bit rng to show them a "mini version" of C's rand. The period will be shorter and therefore more obvious… you can print the complete period (256 bytes) on screen. Seeding the rng in +1 steps and printing the next 256 bytes will show them they're actually only rotating a sequence of 256 predicable bytes. After that, it shouldn't be a huge step to convince them  that bigger numbers don't fix the predictability problem. Also, the 8-bit version provides a playground to build upon towards *attacking* MSVC's implementation.

**Related to *"references that attack fixed LCG"*…**

There is a paper that might be interesting for you to take a look at:

- ["How to crack a Linear Congruential Generator"](http://www.reteam.org/papers/e59.pdf)

It includes a *C* code example which allows the calculation of the seed used in an LCG.

**Related to *"graphical calculator"*…**

Well, it is probably not what you were thinking of as it doesn't attack any LCG, but there is a piece of software that allows to experiment with the parameters of an LCG and which visualizes the subtle correlations between the pseudo-random numbers successively created by an LCG.

[image: screenshot of the software]

You can grab either the English or the German version at
http://www.vias.org/simulations/simusoft_lincong.html