# Predicting Java's PRNG using partial output

Tags: cryptanalysis, random-number-generator

I have a program (a game) that uses Java's `nextInt` function with parameter 0x10000 to get a random 16-bit number.
Java's `nextInt()` is an 48-bit seed LCG with the following formula:

```
seed[n+1] = (seed[n] * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xB) mod (1 << 48)
```

`nextInt()` is implemented in such a way that the random number I receive is the current seed's most significant 16 bits when given argument 0x10000. [Java only does this for an argument that is a power of two]

So let me describe the situation: In the game, I get to have two sequential outputs of `nextInt(0x10000)`, `R[i]` and `R[i+1]` (which are respectively `seed[i]` and `seed[i+1]`'s top 16 bits).

My question is: **what information can I extrapolate about the next output of** `randInt()` (`R[i+2]`) **?**

EDIT: I'm in a situation in which a bruteforce of even more than 30,000 steps is not practical..and all I have are these two consecutive outputs. So, is it even feasible extracting some info given these restrictions? (And please be gentle, I don't have any knowledge in math beyond high school)

Comment: Thanks for fixing the statement. An idea: count the entropy in your givens and unknowns, and get an estimate of what remains unknown (that does not sound encouraging for accurately predicting `R[i+2]`). Ah if you had three values of `R[]`, even non-contiguous... Other idea: the question is similar enough to [this one](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/10608/555) that perhaps the method in [that answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/10629/555) can help to compute the exact distribution of the possible `R[i+2]` given `R[i]` and `R[i+1]`, assuming flat random `seed[0]`; I don't know for sure.

Comment: With above hypothesis, you can conclude something like: if `R[i]`=42 and `R[i+1]`=2014, then for certain `R[i+2]` is not among {0, 4, 9, 12, 13, 21, 24, 33, 38, 45, 46, 54, 68, 71, 80, 83, 92, 95, 100, 104, ..}, and it has odds 3/65537 to be among {201, 888, 1517, 1959, 2402, 3031, 3717, 4160, 4346, 4789, 5231, 6547, 6989, ..}. In a game, that could help. My quick and dirty brute program to compute such statistics runs in seconds for any given (`R[i]`, `R[i+1]`) pairs (it is markedly above your 30k steps bound, but likely that can be improved by the method I pointed to).

Comment: You say algorithms that involve 30,000 steps are not feasible.  Frankly: I'm super-skeptical about that claim. Have you tried implementing such a thing?  Such a computation will probably finish in microseconds.  I find it hard to imagine that this is too slow.

Comment: Correction: in my above [comment](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/13160/555#comment28420_13160), I wish there would be: it has odds 3/65537 to be _any of the values in_ {201, 888, 1517, 1959, 2402, 3031, 3717, 4160, 4346, 4789, 5231, 6547, 6989, ..}; these are the smaller exceptionally _likely_ values for `R[i+2]`, assuming flat distribution of `seed` , `R[i]`=42 and `R[i+1]`=2014.

Comment: Zerith, is there anything missing from D.W.'s answer? Because IMHO it could be marked as accepted answer otherwise.

Comment: **Note**: this is about *implementation details* of the `Random` class in Java. The fully compatible `SecureRandom` class in Java does normally produce secure random output (seeded or produced by the system) - given a default installation on a supported OS anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming this generator is well-seeded, you probably can't learn much about the next output.  You observe two outputs, so 32 bits in total.  The state of the generator is 48 bits.  Thus, there will probably be about $2^{16}$ states of the generator that are compatible with your two observations.  This means that most of the 16-bit values for the next output are (heuristically) likely to be possible.

Thus, your best bet might be to look at how the generator is seeded.  I have a vague recollection that Java's PRNG is poorly seeded, using a seed that has less than 48 bits of entropy.  If this is the case, then it might be possible to predict the next output, by enumerating candidates for the initial seed and seeing which ones are consistent with the outputs you've observed.

---

If you need to enumerate which values for the next output are possible, here is a way to do it.

The naive way is to enumerate all $2^{32}$ possible values of `seed[i]` (you know its top 16 bits, thanks to your knowledge of `R[i]`, so you just need to enumerate all possibilities for its low 32 bits), then test which ones are compatible with the observed value of `R[i+1]`, and for each one that survives, compute the resulting value of `R[i+2]`.  This takes about $2^{32}$ steps of computation, so you can probably make it run in a few seconds or tens of seconds of computation power.

With a little bit of cleverness, you can make this run a lot faster.  Since we know the value of `R[i+1]`, we know the range of possible values for `seed[i+1]`: in particular, we know that `2^32 * R[i+1] <= seed[i+1] <= 2^32 * R[i+1] + 2^32 - 1`.  Also, we know that `seed[i+1] = 0x5DEECE66D * seed[i] + 11 - c * 2^48` for some `c` in the range `0x5DEEC * R[i] <= c <= 0x5DEED * (R[i]+1)`.  Moreover, we know the top 16 bits of `seed[i]`, so we can write `seed[i] = 2^32 * R[i] + x`, for some integer `x` satisfying `0 <= x <= 2^32 - 1`.

Combining all of this, it follows that

`2^32 * R[i+1] <= 0x5DEECE66D * 2^32 * R[i] + 0x5DEECE66D * x + 11 - c * 2^48 <= 2^32 * R[i+1] + 2^32 - 1`

or equivalently,

`(2^32 * R[i+1] - 0x5DEECE66D00000000 * R[i] - 11 - c * 2^48)/0x5DEECE66D <= x <= (2^32 * R[i+1] - 0x5DEECE66D00000000 * R[i] + 2^{32} - 12 - c * 2^48)/0x5DEECE66D`

This range is of width less than 1, so if you know the left-hand-side and the right-hand-side, you can immediately infer `x`.

Thus, if we know `c`, then the value of `x` is determined, which reveals `seed[i]` and thus the next output of the generator.  Finally, there are only about `0x5DEED`$\approx 380,000$ possible values of `c`.

This gives an algorithm that enumerates all possible values for the next output, using about $380,000$ steps of computation.  We enumerate over all $380,000$ possible values of `c`; for each possible value of `c`, we round `(2^32 * R[i+1] - 0x5DEECE66D00000000 * R[i] + 2^{32} - 12 - c * 2^48)/0x5DEECE66D` down to the nearest integer, call it `x`, and then we infer the value of `seed[i]` (namely, `seed[i] = 2^32 * R[i] + x`) and run the generator for two steps to observe the implied next output.  We collect all possible next outputs of the generator.  This gives us the set of all possible values for the next output.  Each iteration uses just a few simple arithmetic operations, and we do $380,000$ iterations, so this procedure should run extremely fast: in milliseconds or less.

Comment: The results that I [reported](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/13160/555#comment28420_13160) are per _the naive way_ in this answer; run time is about 7 seconds on an [old CPU](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/K8/AMD-Athlon%2064%20X2%205050e%20-%20ADH5050IAA5DO%20%28ADH5050DOBOX%29.html), so D.W.'s estimates are excellent. Adding _a little bit of cleverness_ would bring runtime to a blink.