# With the random numbers generated, can I know which RNG seed was used?

Tags: algorithm-design

My teacher challenged us to find out which seed was used to generate some random numbers. I would like to know if it is possible to decipher the seed using the generated numbers (break the linear congruence algorithm). If possible, I ask you to explain how to do it.

Comment: how much do you know about the algo and the sample start point?

Comment: If you know it is a linear congruence algorithm, then yes. Look for example [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/51686/29574) and my answer to it for a how-to.

Answer (score 1):

If the RNG is cryptographically strong, then you should not be able to do any better than the naive brute force: try each seed until you get matching random numbers.

If this is a homework question, then I would guess that either they used a very small seed (like "3" or "15"), or the RNG is not cryptographic strength and with some time analyzing the linear congruence algorithm, you might see how to invert it.