# Is it possible to predict a randomly generated BigInteger that uses Java's default Random library?

Tags: cryptanalysis, random-number-generator

I've seen it posted on different forms [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14616163/how-to-obtain-the-nth-random-nextint-value) and [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/51686/how-to-determine-the-next-number-from-javas-random-method) that explain how `java.util.Random` library uses a **linear congruential pseudorandom number generator** which can be cracked using two values. Can this type of exploit go one level deeper and guess the `nextByte` data used to fill in the rest of a BigInteger value?

```
private static Random generator = new Random();

public static String uncrackableRandomNumber() {
    return new BigInteger(128, generator);
}
```

[A snippet of the additional layer of byte generation](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/f4d80957e89a19a29bb9f9807d2a28351ed7f7df/src/share/classes/java/math/BigInteger.java#L492) using `java.util.Random` (`rnd`).

```
public BigInteger(int numBits, Random rnd) {
      this(1, randomBits(numBits, rnd));
  }

private static byte[] randomBits(int numBits, Random rnd) {
  if (numBits < 0)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("numBits must be non-negative");
  int numBytes = (int) (((long) numBits + 7) / 8); // avoid overflow
  byte[] randomBits = new byte[numBytes];

  // Generate random bytes and mask out any excess bits
  if (numBytes > 0) {
    rnd.nextBytes(randomBits);
    int excessBits = 8 * numBytes - numBits;
    randomBits[0] &= (1 << (8 - excessBits)) - 1;
  }
  return randomBits;
}
```

The first two numbers are: `233458857748780331814340414981023411537` and `141610568161066839752374346774468879751`, how can I determine the next number given only this information?

Comment: Yes its possible and easy. Hint: see what [`nextBytes`](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/Random.java#L212) does, use that to get two consecutive 32-bit outputs by the RNG, which allows to compute the full state.

Comment: @fgrieu Was hoping for a solution rather than a hint, but I'll read up on `nextBytes`. Glad to see the return of `nextInt`.

Comment: I (now) realize there's a recent [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/hacking/comments/gegevi/predicting_the_next_biginteger_value_in_java/) with a similar question, under another name, stating that the purpose is breaking a 'web app'. While making the mistake of using the Java default RNG for security purpose is laughable, it's still my policy not to participate in attack of non-clearly-evil deployed crypto. While homework or CTF seems just as likely, neither of the three options is enticing me to give more than a hint. That's educative, again that's easy, just do it, you'll feel good.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the answer plainly yes by simple deduction?  The BigInteger constructor is simply a linear function as: BigInt ~ F(LCG).  Ergo if LCG is predictable, BitInt is too. It's not much deeper.

Could you do BigInt ~ F(SecureRandom)?