# Reverse Java seed using outputs generated from nextInt(6)+1

Tags: cryptanalysis, random-number-generator

Given a set of numbers within the range of 1-6:

[3,4,3,4,5,6,2,3,1,5,2,3,6,2,2,3,3,6,6,4,5,2,5,3,5,2,4,4,2,6,3,6,1,5,1,3,6,1,1,2,2,4,5,3,1,2,3,4,4,6]

generated using Java's nextInt(6)+1, is it possible to reverse engineer this to find the seed?

Upon investigating Java's source-code I understand this is how the nextInt() method works:

```
public static int nextInt(int n){
        if (n <= 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be positive");
        if ((n & -n) == n) // i.e., n is a power of 2
            return (int) ((n * (long) next(31)) >> 31);
        int bits, val;
        do
            {
                bits = next(31);
                val = bits % n;
            }
        while (bits - val + (n - 1) < 0); //do, until its a positive number
        return val;
    }
```

Since **n** in this case is 6, it is not a power of 2 so it carries out this part of the code:

```
do
  {
    bits = next(31);
    val = bits % n;
  }
  while (bits - val + (n - 1) < 0); //do, until its a positive number
  return val;
```

it now calls next(31) and this is the code where it essentially runs through a linear-congruential generator

```
public static int next(int bits){
  seed = (seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & ((1L << 48) - 1);
  return (int) (seed >>> (48 - bits));
}
```

this 31bit number is returned as an int and assigned into **bits**

Finally we do **bits** % 6 and this gives the final value.

I have a few questions:

**(1) what is the purpose of this line of code?**

`while (bits - val + (n - 1) < 0);`

**(2) How does one reverse engineer and find the seed from a set of numbers generated from this procedure?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> what is the purpose of this line of code?
> `while (bits - val + (n - 1) < 0);`

From a syntactic perspective, it ends the `do` opened above. From a functional perspective, it makes the pseudo-random number generated uniform on the specified interval. I'll focus on the later aspect.

Assume `n` was $3\cdot2^{29}\,$ (that is `3<<29`) rather than $6$. After the statement `bits = next(31);` this quantity is uniformly random in $[0,2^{31})$. Therefore `val = bits % n;` is

- `bits` with probability 75%; and then uniform on $[0,3\cdot2^{29})$
- or `bits-(3<<29)` with probability 25%; and then uniform on $[0,2^{29})$

It follows that before the `while`, `val` is in $[0,2^{29})$ with probability 50%, in $[2^{29},3\cdot2^{29})$ with probability 50%. The second interval is twice as large as the first, and we see that `val` is very far from uniform on the whole interval $[0,3\cdot2^{29})\ $!

The `while` repeats the loop when in the problematic second bullet, and thus makes the outcome uniform on the full interval $[0,3\cdot2^{29})$.

---

**Alternate explanation with small numbers**

Imagine that, starting from $b=0$, four times: we double $b$, then add $1$ to $b$ if we get a tail from a fair coin throw. The outcome is $b$ a nonnegative integer less than $2^4=16$, and each of these $16$ integers is equally likely. That is, the outcome is a discrete uniform random number $b$ in $[0,16)$.

From this we want a uniform random number $v$ in $[0,6)\,$ just like `nextInt(6)` is tasked to do. Problem is, if we use a fixed assignment of values of $b$ from $[0,16)$ to values of $v$ in $[0,6)$, the outcome can't be uniform. The most even we can get is that $4$ values of $v$ have probability $3/16$, and the $2$ other $2/16$. Think of separating $16$ mints (the $b$) into $6$ persons (the $v$).

A simple solution to that is: when $b$ is in $[0,6)$, that's our $v$. When $b$ is in $[6,12)\,$, our $v$ is $b-6$. Otherwise, we try again, generating another $b$ using coin throws. That's what the code does in it's `do … while` loop, only with $2^{31}$ using `next(31)` where our analogy uses $2^4$ and coin throws; using `bits` for $b$, and `val` for $v$.

---

**Off-topic: what's up with `bits - val + (n - 1) < 0` ?**

[One wonders](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/189157) how `while (bits - val + (n - 1) < 0);` manages to do what's described above. `bits` is in range `[0, 0x7FFFFFFF]`, `n` is 6, `val` is `bits % n`, thus `val < bits` holds and `bits - val` is non-negative. But it does *not* follow that `bits - val + (n - 1)` is non-negative, because the operations are carried per [two's-complement arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) over 32-bit.

That's how `int` works in Java, many other computer languages, and most modern computer hardware when manipulating signed integers as a 32-bit quantities. If the `int` quantities `u` and `v` represent the integers $u$ and $v$, these integers are both in range $[-2^{31},2^{31}-1]$, then `u + v` is an `int` quantity representing an integer $w$ in range $[-2^{31},2^{31}-1]$ with $u+v\equiv w\bmod2^{32}$, that is by definition $u+v-w$ a multiple of $2^{32}$, and depending on values of $(u,v)$ that multiple can be $0$, $2^{32}$, or $-2^{32}$. In the end, $w$ is the integer $((u+v+2^{31})\bmod2^{32})-2^{31}$. That arithmetic is commutative, associative, has neutral zero, and every element has an opposite. A caveat: $-2^{31}$, that is `-0x80000000`, shares with zero the property of being it's own opposite.

So for example if `bits` was $2^{31}-2$, `val` is $0$, `bits - val` is $2^{31}-2$, `bits - val + (n - 1)` is $((2^{31}-2+(6-1)+2^{31})\bmod2^{32})-2^{31}$, that is $((2^{32}+3)\bmod2^{32})-2^{31}=3-2^{31}$, and that's negative.

For those that just want to move along: the condition `bits - val + (n - 1) < 0` is logically equivalent to `bits - val >= ((long)1<<31) + 1 - n` (with no overflow and only non-negative quantities, thanks `long` being 64-bit).

It should now be apparent that `bits - val + (n - 1) < 0` holds when `bit` is at the top of its interval `[0, 0x7FFFFFFF]`. It is left as an exercise to the reader to show that the rest of the interval contains a multiple of `n` integers, thus all the `n` values of `val` on exit of the loop are exactly as likely, under the assumption that all values of `bits` are.

---

> How does one reverse engineer

That's already done. The question *has* reverse-engineered the algorithm, and even more than this: simplified the code from what it is in a recent Java environment by removing the thread-safety stuff (or traveling back in time to get the source before that was added); and thought about removing the part of the code that is demonstrably unreachable in the circumstance.

> and find the seed from a set of numbers generated from this procedure?

Next step towards that goes: compute the probability that the condition in the `while` statement is true when `n` is $6$, and decide what can be done about this case.

Then proceed. There's several paths to resolution:

- Brute force, trying all $2^{48}$ initial state values. This is feasible, but inelegant and resource-hungry.
- Reducing the above search space by a factor of $6$ by exploiting the first result available.
- Using that $6$ is even to get 18 bits of the seed out of 48 (with fair probability), then brute force the rest. That's relatively simple and educative. It's outlined [in this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2087/555) of mine. Some combinations with the above tweaks work.
- A that-could-well-work-but-I-didn't-bother-to-try approach using SAT solvers (in same answer).

Likely there are other approaches, but if there's anything readily applicable [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/20495/555) or [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2089/555), I missed it.

If stuck, state at what point at the bottom of the present question.

Comment: 1) For the bit about probability distributions being uniform or not, would I need to understand a fair bit of statistics particularly on probability distributions?

2) Would this mathematical knowledge be necessary to compute the probability that the condition in the while statement is true when n is 6?

Comment: @javaproblem201 : A working intuitive notion of (discrete) probability will do, without the notion of probability distribution. To visualize the problem with small numbers, try turning an [hex dice](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:D16_HEX_dice.JPG) throw into a  random integer in $[0,6)$. Just examine all the 16 cases, what's the corresponding outcome, deduce the probability of each outcome. Uniform means equal probabilities.

Comment: I fail to see how the condition `(bits - val + (n - 1) < 0)` would achieve proper uniform sampling. Assuming `bits`, `val` and `n` are positive, $\mathrm{val} \leq \mathrm{bits}$ always holds, since `val` is `bits` modulo `n`. Therefore `bits - val` is always non-negative. Therefore, unless $n$ is 0, `(bits - val + (n - 1)` is also non-negative. I've tried it out, and when I invert the loop condition, the program does not halt. I don't know what this code is trying to achieve, but I'm fairly certain it's not achieving rejection sampling.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116682/discussion-on-answer-by-fgrieu-reverse-java-seed-using-outputs-generated-from-ne).

Comment: @fgrieu Many thanks for your help and sorry I forgot to press accept answer even yes it solved my original question.

For your referral to my ultimate one ((int)Math.random()*6+1) it involved mathematics that I lack which after some effort I decide its not possible for me at this point, would it be possible to ask you to write a working program that could crack that, and perhaps someday when i know lattice theory I could figure out how it works?

Comment: @javaproblem201: What about making a question about it, on the tune of: how do we find the state of LCG $x_{i+1}\gets a\,x_i+b\bmod m$ given consecutive values of $d_i\gets\lfloor c\,x_i/m\rfloor$, and $a$, $b$, $c$, $m$? With application to Java `(int)(Math.random()*6)` as $a=25214903917$, $b=11$, $m=2^{48}$ and $c=6$. I asked [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/86530/555) in hope solving this would become crystal-clear to all, including me. There's a nice answer, but it still does not cut it for me. I put it in my _interesting things to try_ list.